# rd5 installed php mysql apachi hosting providers

Tags: php, mysql, codeigniter

I want to use install Red5 1.0 RC1 on  server

but  i ask from hosting provider they say.

```
this not supported for sharing hosting.
```

so i want to change my hosting. 
      i have  `CodeIgniter` application.it has chat application for work  this 
         it  want to rd5 installed.

i want to host my `CodeIgniter` application  with rd5 supported host.

i want to know best   Red5 1.0 RC1 supported PHP  MySQL Apache  hosting

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You don't have to change you entire hosting for this, red5 eats a lot of memory, so you're better off purchasing a red5 or wowza service that's remotely installed & managed by a professional provider which should work just fine.

If you insist on doing it yourself, then you'll have to purchase a VPS with at least 2 GB of RAM to make your stuffs work (this will incur higher costs ofcourse as you'll need to purchase a control panel license + a VPS)